# I can't get my minimax algorithm for tic tac toe to work as desired

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe, minimax

Hi everyone I'm trying implement minimax into my tic tac toe game with javascript but I just can't seem to get it to work. I've tried everything I can think of but the ai just makes horrible moves so I'm sure I messed something up but I've spent the whole night trying to spot my mistake and It's been no use.

I've noticed that my maximizing players bestScore is pretty random. It can be 1, -1 or -Infinity. On the other hand the minimizing players bestScore is always either -1 or -Infinity. I think that is relevant to the problem.

Here is the code which is relevant:

```
const makeMove = () => {
    let bestScore = -Infinity;
    let move;
    let board = Gameboard.gameBoard;
    for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (typeof board[i] !== 'string') {
            const originalValue = board[i];
            board.splice(i, 1, Gameflow.p2.sign);
            let score = minimax(board, 0, false);
            console.log(score);
            board.splice(i, 1, originalValue);
            if (score > bestScore) {
                bestScore = score;
                move = i;
            }
        }
    }

    board.splice(move, 1, Gameflow.p2.sign);
};

const minimax = (board, depth, isMaximizing) => {
    let result = Gameflow.checkResult();
    if (result != null) {
        return scores[result];
    }
    if (isMaximizing) {
        let bestScore = -Infinity;
        for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            if (typeof board[i] !== 'string') {
                const originalValue = board[i];
                board.splice(i, 1, Gameflow.p2.sign);
                let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, false);
                board.splice(i, 1, originalValue);
                bestScore = Math.max(score, bestScore);
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    } else {
        let bestScore = Infinity;
        for (let i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            if (typeof board[i] !== 'string') {
                const originalValue = board[i];
                board.splice(i, 1, Gameflow.p1.sign);
                let score = minimax(board, depth + 1, true);
                board.splice(i, 1, originalValue);
                bestScore = Math.min(score, bestScore);
            }
        }
        return bestScore;
    }
};
const scores = {
    O: 1,
    X: -1,
    tie: 0,
};
```

I hope I've been descriptive enough but if any clarifications are needed I'll be happy to provide more info.  If you wish to have a look at the entire code here is the link: https://github.com/Gianluca-Cioni/tic-tac-toe/blob/ai/index.js